# No value given for one or more required parameters error vb.net

Tags: vb.net

```
no_hp = TextBox1.Text
alamat = TextBox2.Text
password = TextBox3.Text

cmd = New OleDbCommand("UPDATE [user] SET no_hp = '" & CInt(TextBox1.Text) & "',alamat = " & TextBox2.Text & ", pin ='" & CInt(TextBox3.Text) & "' WHERE id = " & id & "", conn)
cmd.Connection = conn
cmd.ExecuteReader()
```

i was trying to update my access database with the following error
i cant seem to see where i did wrong
i already changed the data type from the textbox to match with the data types used in the database
the no_hp and pin is integer so i converted it to Cint but it doesnt seem to work
i already tried to substitute it to a variable but still it didnt work
please tell me where i did wrong

Comment: See the difference between [OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/979byfca(v=vs.110).aspx)  and [OleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx). Maybe also to [OleDbCommand.Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Use Parameters to avoid SQL injection, a malious attack that can mean data loss. The parameter names in Access do not matter. It is the order that they are added which must match the order in the SQL statement that matters.
The Using...End Using statements ensure that you objects are closed and disposed even it there is an error. This is most important for connections.
You con't need to set the connection property of the command because you passed the connection in the constructor of the command.
ExcuteReader is for retrieving data. Use ExecuteNonQuery to update, insert of delete.

```
Private Sub UpdateUsers()
        Using conn As New OleDbConnection("Your connection string")
            Using cmd = New OleDbCommand("UPDATE [user] SET no_hp = ?,alamat = ?, pin =? WHERE id = ?", conn)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("nohp", OleDbType.Integer).Value = CInt(TextBox1.Text)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("alamat", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox2.Text
                cmd.Parameters.Add("pword", OleDbType.Integer).Value = CInt(TextBox3.Text)
                cmd.Parameters.Add("id", OleDbType.Integer).Value = id
                conn.Open()
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End Using
        End Using
End Sub
```

Comment: @Rein if my answer was helpful, please mark it as the accepted answer with the check mark (tick mark) to the left of the answer.